# Having trouble in solving this permutations problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number 916238457 is an example of a nine-digit number which contains each of the digit 1 to 9 exactly once. It also has the property that the digits 1 to 5 occur in 9.7-7-6 their natural order, while the digits 1 to 6 do not. Find the number of such numbers.

According to me the answer should be  9 * 8 * 7 * 6  as no. 6 has 9 places available, 7 as 8 and so on til ,9 has 6 places .. so we take permutations of all these cases and all the other numbers i.e 1to 5 , will be arranged in increasing order in the vacant places .
But the answer is given as 2520

Comment: Hint : Read the question carefully for the 1 to 6 part

Comment: I did think about this line... Then I concluded that it meant that the order is maintained only till number 5 after that the number can be arranged in any form ..is this incorrect ?

Comment: I think it means that 1 to 6 should strictly not be in its natural order, taking this constraint into consideration you get 2520 as the answer

Answer (score 2):

First let's select 5 spaces for 1 to 5

That would be :

$\binom{9}{5}$ = 126
And there is justone way to arrange 1 to 5

Now there are 4! ways to arrange the remaining digits

Thus, the total number of such numbers is 3024.

(Notice that this $\textbf{would}$ include cases where 1 to 6 are in order )

Now you subtract the cases where 1 to 6 were in order. So you chose 6 spaces and just one way to arrange them.

$\binom{9}{6}$ = 84

For the remaining three digits you have 3! ways to arrange them.

Thus the nine digit numbers where 1 to 6 are in order will be

84×3! = 504

You subtract these types of nine digit numbers from the numbers where 1 to 5 are in order but we are unsure of 6.
I.e-

Number of 9 digit numbers where$\textbf{1 to 5 are in order but 1 to 6 aren't}$= number of 9 digit numbers where $\textbf{1 to 5 are in order}$ - number of 9 digit numbers where $\textbf{1 to 6 are in order}$

Thus by doing that you get :-

3024 - 504= 2520